# "git checkout develop --recurse-submodules" make submodule's HEAD detached

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have parent project `A`,
`git branch -a`:

```
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

`A`'s `develop` branch depends on a submodule `subA`, but `master` branch doesn't.

and `subA` have these branches:

`git branch -a`:

```
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

the `.gitmodules` file :

```
[submodule "subA"]
        path = subA
        url = https://someDomain/suA.git
        branch = develop
```

here's the problem,

I get into the parent project's directory, switch from branch `develop` to `master`, everything goes well cause `master` branch doesn't depend on `subA`, but when I use  `git checkout develop --recurse-submodules` to switch back to the `develop` branch, the `suA`'s branch status is always like this,

```
* (HEAD detached at refs/heads/develop)
  develop
  master
```

I know I can fix it by `git checkout develop`,  but I want to figure it out why `--recurse-submodules` doesn't work, and whether is there a solution to let submodules switch branches from the parent projects correctly.

git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+detached+HEAD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `recurse-submodules` only makes sure that you will be on the right commit but won't notice this inbetween your local branches.

> --[no-]recurse-submodules
>
> Using --recurse-submodules will update the content of all initialized
> submodules according to the commit recorded in the superproject. If
> local modifications in a submodule would be overwritten the checkout
> will fail unless -f is used. If nothing (or --no-recurse-submodules)
> is used, the work trees of submodules will not be updated.

It is simply setting the HEAD to the commited (in your project) version of your submodule.